# Vue.js create dynamic AJAX response based multiple components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I am trying to create an SPA using dynamic server response. 
For e.g. data returned is:

```
components: [
{
    name: "Parent1",
    data: {...},
    children: [
        {
           component: {
               name: "Child1",
               data: {...},
               children: []
            }
        },
        {
            component: {
                name: "Child2",
                data: {...},
                children: []
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Parent2",
    data: {...},
    children: [
        {
           component: {
               name: "Child1",
               data: {...},
               children: []
            }
        }
    ]
}    
]
```

What I would like to do is define parent components and children separately.
i.e. Components list:

```
- Parent : Common parent with data1 and data2 displayed, instantiates Children   as needed         
- Child1
- Child2
```

Anyone have any ideas for the best approach?

Comment: It might be possible. What have you tried and what is / isn't working?

Comment: I can create a parent component in the DOM using :

`<template>`
`<div class="page">`
`<h1> page for {{ $route.params.id }}</h1>`
`<tag1 v-bind:data1=data1></tag1>`
`</div>`
`</template>`

Comment: What I would like to do is not specify `tag1` in the component tags at the top, instead instantiate based on the XHR reponse.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vue. You might want to tag `json` to get more responses. For data modeling, you can also check this out - http://jsonapi.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `component` with `is`?

```
<component :is="componentType"></component>
```

This is the **dynamic components** feature of Vue.js

A very simple example: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/ZLjrRX?editors=1010

see the document here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: I used this and works perfectly:
`<component v-for="item in info.components" :is="item.type" v-bind:data="item.data"></component>`

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this:

**Parent API URL:** `www.example.com/api/parent/parent_id` (generally known as API endpoint)

**Server Response:**

```js
{
    data: {
        type: "Parent",
        id: "parent123",
        name: "Parent 1",
        children_ids: ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
    },
    included: [
        {type: "Child", id: "c1", name: "Child 1", ...},
        {type: "Child", id: "c2", name: "Child 2", ...},
        {type: "Child", id: "c3", name: "Child 3", ...},
    ]
}
```

**Note:**

1. Every data item needs to have an ID. Your example does not mention ID anywhere.
2. This example roughly follows the guidelines in http://jsonapi.org/ but you are free to follow whatever works for you, as long as you document it for the team.
3. This example attempts to load the actual data in `response.data` object, and side-loads children data in `response.included` array, thus keeping `parent` and `child` separate. You need to handle this response convention in Vue.js, preferably using Vuex as the store.

If you intend to follow this example, you also need to make sure the child API endpoints are active and can be independently accessed. This is helpful if your Vue App is loaded directly with child URL.

Sample child API endpoint:

1. `www.example.com/api/parent/parent_id/child/child_id` (if child_id is **NOT** unique)
2. `www.example.com/api/child/child_id` (if child_id is unique)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I just wanted to present some example for the Vue question. The API endpoints are handled as per the JSON API specification. :)